# Website went DOWN! Changed theme on word press

Tags: php, wordpress

I was changing the theme on word press and this popped up. I am ready to fix it but I don't know code... at all. ![says require one and failed opening. gave the line 173 and said include path ='.:/user/ and so on

```
167.            // Return
168.            return false;
169.            
170.        }
171. 
172.        /**
173.         * Get the nav ID.
174.         *
175.         * @since 1.4.7
176.         */
177.        public static function get_nav_id() {
```

> Warning: require_once(/home/content/85/3750385/html/bigbarberbrand.co/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/inc/third/class-elementor.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/85/3750385/html/bigbarberbrand.co/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/functions.php on line 173
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/content/85/3750385/html/bigbarberbrand.co/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/inc/third/class-elementor.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/85/3750385/html/bigbarberbrand.co/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/functions.php on line 173

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have enough information to help you. This small snippet of code doesn't show anything related to your error description. It looks like you're missing a required file, but the question lacks enough context to tell you which one or why. The lines you showed contain just the end of one function and the beginning of another. There is no requirement of other files in this snippet, and the line you mentioned, 173, doesn't contain any executable code at all.

Comment: The format got messed up, I can't post an image because I'm new.

Comment: Did you delete the other theme's folder? Because those missing files are in a theme folder ("oceanwp"), and if you deleted that, they won't be found, which would explain that warning and error message. If not: Can you switch back to the other theme?

Comment: Looks like `/home/content/85/3750385/html/bigbarberbrand.co/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/inc/third/class-elementor.php` is the file that is missing. It is included from the other file, `/home/content/85/3750385/html/bigbarberbrand.co/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/functions.php`. The cause? Hard to say. Maybe the theme was not installed completely before. Since you just changed theme, you now selected the broken theme. You could try to re-upload the theme, or change back to another. You may need to dive into your website's database for that, if you have access to it.

Comment: The server is telling you that it tried to load a PHP file from your `oceanwp` theme (inc/third/class-elementor.php) but it didn't find it. Reupload your `oceanwp` theme and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: So there nothing to tweak to the line? I can't log into word press but I have fetcher and can edit code and look at other files... what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your database is likely still intact. Backup your plugins folder and your wp-config.php file which contains the sql DB info and keep them somewhere safe.

Reupload the wordpress installation, insert your wp-config.php file that you backed up.

Log in, install your theme again now that your wordpress installation is back. You will not lose data.

Revive your plugins folder that you backed up and replace the new one that has almost nothing in it, now you have your plugins again in your healthy environment.

This should get you where you want to be (based on the information you provided) and your new theme should be working without conflict if it is indeed stable for your version of Wordpress.

All in all, something is missing that the PHP is trying to reference but without knowing more, I can't troubleshoot specifically (and I'm not positive anyone else could).

My suggestion nonetheless isn't a last resort. Sometimes things happen in WP and this is simply what needs to be done.